# Detecting operator and operand errors in expression string

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to detect where and what error occurred in a regular infix expression. The first thing that I came up with looks like this...

```
String expression = "(12 * 12) + (12 * 9)";
int numOfDigits = 0;
int numOfOperators = 0;
boolean onDigit = false;

for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
  char ch = expression.charAt(i);

  if (Character.isDigit(ch) && !onDigit) {
    numOfDigits += 1;
    onDigit = true;
  } else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*') {
    numOfOperators += 1;
    onDigit = false;
  } else if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
    onDigit = false;
  }
}

if (numOfDigits - 1 != numOfOperators) {
  System.out.println("Missing operand(s) or operator(s) in expression");
}
```

The only issue with this is that I can't detect where in the expression the error is coming from. At this point, I decided to go with something that looks like this as it can detect where in the string the error is coming from. The only problem that I am having with it is that if there is an operator at the end of the string I can't figure out how to allow the program to detect that and display an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
  char ch = expression.charAt(i);

  if (lastType.equalsIgnoreCase("") && (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*')) {
    System.out.printf("Missing operand at: %d\n", lastLocation + 1);
    break;
  }

  if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    if (!onDigit) {
      if (lastType.equalsIgnoreCase("digit")) {
        System.out.printf("Missing operator at: %d\n", lastLocation + lenOfDigit);
        break;
      }
      lastType = "Digit";
      lastLocation = i + 1;
      numOfDigits += 1;
      onDigit = true;
    }
    lenOfDigit++;
  } else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*') {
    if (lastType.equalsIgnoreCase("operator")) {
      System.out.printf("Missing operand at: %d\n", lastLocation + 1);
      break;
    }
    lastType = "Operator";
    lastLocation = i + 1;
    numOfOperators += 1;
    onDigit = false;
    lenOfDigit = 0;
  } else if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
    onDigit = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Throw is all away and use a proper expression parser, e.g. recursive descent or the Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm, There is no substitute. Hand-crafted methods won't do.

Comment: Any other suggestion(s) you might have as a starting point?

Comment: I have already made two general and two specific suggestions. Why are you now asking me to provide more?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to implement them

Comment: These are standard techniques. Look them up in Wikipedia. Plenty of questions and answers about them here too.

Answer (score -2):

You can traverse the string backwards and find the first index where `Character.isDigit()` is `true`. Then simultaneously find the first index where the character is an operator. If the index for the operator is larger than the index for the digit, then you've found the discrepancy where an operator is the last character in the expression.

EDIT:

I'm assuming you want to detect when an expression has an operator that is not followed by any digit.

Eg: `"(12 * 12) + (12 * 9) +"`

You could detect this with:

```
int lastDigitIndex = -1;
int lastOperatorIndex = -1;

for (int i = expression.length()-1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    char ch = expression.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isDigit(ch) && lastDigitIndex == -1)
        lastDigitIndex = i;
    else if((ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*') && lastOperatorIndex == -1)
        lastOperatorIndex = i;

    if (lastDigitIndex != -1 && lastOperatorIndex != -1)
        break;  
}

if (lastOperatorIndex > lastDigitIndex)
{
    //Error found
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer more?

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider marking it as such. If not, feel free to let me know.

Comment: The only issue is that it doesn't detect where in the string the issue occurred. With my attempt I got it to detect that just not if there was an operator at the end

Comment: @AlexLowe The issue is that there is no guarantee it will detect anything. It's just a piece of ad-hoc code, not written according to any accepted principle. Do not use.